# Buffer.isBuffer is not a function in Angular 6.1.10 when using XLSX

Tags: typescript, angular6, xlsx

Trying to implement Excel sheet to generate from Array. Using below Code it shows `buffer.isbuffer` is not function.
Same code works perfectly fine when using separately outside the project.

Can someone please help on this issue? Thanks in advance

### ExcelService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {

  constructor() {
  }

  static toExportFileName(excelFileName: string): string {
    return `${excelFileName}_export_${new Date().getTime()}.xlsx`;
  }

  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {Sheets: {'data': worksheet}, SheetNames: ['data']};
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, ExcelService.toExportFileName(excelFileName));
  }
}
```

### app.component.ts

```
exportToExcel(event) {
    this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(PERSONS, 'persons');
}
```

### app.component.html

`<button (click)="exportToExcel()" class="btn btn-primary">Export to excel</button>`

### model.ts

```
    id: number;
    name: String;
    surname: String;
    age: number;
}


export const PERSONS: Person[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Thomas',
        surname: 'Novicky',
        age: 21
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Adam',
        surname: 'Tracz',
        age: 12
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Steve',
        surname: 'Laski',
        age: 38
    }
];
```

### Console Error

````
VM1526 CommentTableComponent.ngfactory.js:453 ERROR TypeError: Buffer.isBuffer is not a function
    at Function.module.exports.test (VM1423 vendor.js:182405)
    at Object.exports.getTypeOf (VM1423 vendor.js:183869)
    at Object.exports.transformTo (VM1423 vendor.js:183851)
    at JSZipSync.utf8encode (VM1423 vendor.js:183183)
    at JSZipSync.generate (VM1423 vendor.js:183085)
    at write_zip_type (VM1423 vendor.js:210416)
    at writeSync (VM1423 vendor.js:210506)
    at Object.writeFileSync (VM1423 vendor.js:210529)
    at ExcelService.push../src/app/shared/services/files/excel.service.ts.ExcelService.exportAsExcelFile (VM1424 main.js:6982)
    at CommentTableComponent.push../src/app/shared/containers/comment-table/comment-table.component.ts.CommentTableComponent.exportToExcel (VM1424 main.js:4847)```
````

Comment: Did you ever solve this, i am having the same problem but with a different error message ```core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Buffer.isBuffer is not a function
TypeError: Buffer.isBuffer is not a function
    at Object.isBuffer (jszip.min.js:13)```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```js
JSZip.support.nodebuffer = false;
this.excelExportService.export(this.grid, new IgxExcelExporterOptions('FILENAME));
```

[Reference](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/196#issuecomment-69503828)